# Multiplying Using Bitwise Shift Operators Giving TLE

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, multiplication

[Question](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/bit-manipulation/basics-of-bit-manipulation/practice-problems/algorithm/mattey-multiplication-6/)

> Given *N* and *M*, write an equation using left shift operators whose
>   result will be equal to the product *N * M*.
>
> Input : First line has 0 < *T* ≤ 50000 denoting number of test cases.
>   Next *T* lines have two integers 0 < *N, M* ≤ 10¹⁶.
>
> Output : For each test case print an equation for *N * M* resembling
>
> *(N << p1) + (N << p2)+ ...+(N << pk)* where *p1 ≥ p2 ≥ ... ≥ pk*
>    and *k* is minimum.
>
> ```
> SAMPLE INPUT    SAMPLE OUTPUT
>
> 2
> 2 1             (2<<0)
> 2 3             (2<<1) + (2<<0)
> ```
>
> Time Limit: 1.0 sec

My Solution 1st approach

```
int dig = (int)(Math.floor(Math.log10(m)/Math.log10(2))+1);
boolean flag = false;
for(long i = dig; i>=0; --i) {       
      if(((m>>(i-1l)) & 1l) == 1l) {
           if(flag)
               System.out.print(" + ("+n+ "<<"+(i-1)+")");
           else {
               System.out.print("("+n+"<<"+(i-1)+")");
               flag = true; 
                }
             } 
         }
```

Second Approach

```
boolean[] arr = new boolean[dig];
        int i = dig-1;
        while(m > 0) {
            if((m&1) == 1 ) {
                arr[i] = true;
            }
            i--;
            m = m>>1l;
        }
        int j = dig-1;
        for( i = 0; i < dig; ++i) {

            if(arr[i]) {
               if(flag) 
               System.out.print(" + ("+n+"<<"+j+")");
               else {
                   System.out.print("("+n+"<<"+j+")");
                   flag = true;
               }
            }

            j--;
        }
```

In both cases I am getting 5 correct out of 8 and rest 3 are TLE why?

Comment: What does «TLE» mean?

Comment: Time Limit Exceeded. The accept time for each query is 1.0 sec

Comment: If it was *(using left shift operators, write) (an equation)*, it would seem to be using `m>>`, and not `<<`. Without *any* indication what `m` *is*, how are we to know if `m>>` doesn't extend `m`s sign, `m` never reaching 0 with the `Second Approach`? That said, I have no idea why the 1st  should TLE - the second should get IOOBE. I don't see your snippets put out *lines*. I do see a lot of "String adding" of arguments not changing between iterations.

Comment: @greybeard IOOBE? Does it means IndexOutOfBoundsException? And now what can be done to improve it? And I don't fully get what you want to say. "m" is the number by which we are dividing n. Like for example 2 * 3, then n = 2 and m = 3. So I am breaking down this as 3 = 11 in binary so. I have to bit shift 2 by 1 then add it to bit shift 2 by 0. if it was m = 2 then I would not add bit shift of 2 by 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually see anything in both of your approaches preventing some ten-thousands of products of numbers up to 57 bit to be represented as `String`s in one second:
`TLE` *may* be due to `System.out.print()` taking an inordinate amount of time.
That said, use a utility like

```
   /** builds <code>n * m</code> in the form
    * <code>(n&lt;&lt;p1) + (n&lt;&lt;p2) + ... + (n&lt;&lt;pk)</code>
    * using left shift.
    * @param n  (0 < multiplicand <= 10**16)
    * @param m  0 < multiplier <= 10**16
    * @return a verbose <code>String</code> for <code>n * m</code>
    */
    static String verboseBinaryProduct(Object n, long m) {
        int shift = Long.SIZE - Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(m) - 1;
        final long highest = 1 << shift;
        final StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder(42);
        final String chatter = ") + (" + n + "<<";
        final long rest = highest - 1;
        while (true) {
            if (0 != (highest & m))
                binary.append(chatter).append(shift);
            if (0 == (rest & m)) {
                binary.append(')');
                return binary.substring(4);
            }
            m <<= 1;
            shift -= 1;
        }
    }
```

and `System.out.println(verboseBinaryProduct(n, m));`.

Comment: @[greybeard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3789665/greybeard) I am sorry but your third last case is the wrong answer and last two are Runtime Error (NZEC). Please check it.

Comment: `your third last case is the wrong answer` *my*? I didn't try to get a submission to hackerearth accepted. That said, it took me longer to start my IDE than to jot down two more "test cases" (for a total of three) *and* see one error at work. `last two are [NonZeroExitCode]` I presented no `main()`, didn't call `System.exit(~0)`. (*If* hackerearth accepted submissions without disclosure of an email address, I *might* try - with output (&, possibly, input) buffering and, among others, both of your approaches.)